# Replace the Text on events using GLC font rendering library Opengl

Tags: opengl

I have rendered the font on OpenGL window with the help of GLC library, but now if I want to apply some operations on the rendered font, then it is terminating as a Segmentation fault.

The code to render the font is as below,

```
char * msg = "ABCD";
void drawString(char* name, int x, int y){
    ctx = glcGenContext();
    glcContext(ctx);    
    myFont = glcGenFontID();
    glcNewFontFromFamily(myFont, "Courier");
    glcFont(myFont);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity();          
    glOrtho(0.0, 500.0, 500.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glcScale(20,20);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glRasterPos3f(x,y,0);
    glcRenderString(name);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_E && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        msg = "abcd";
}

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "font rendering", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit( ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    }

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    GLint ctx, myFont;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        drawString(msg, 100, 100);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

on pressing `E`, it should change the `ABCD` to `abcd`, but it is not replacing the original text, it is mixing two text.

I understood, there is something issue in creating the context and using it properly, I also tried to use `glcDeleteContext()`, but it is also doing same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the color buffer of the default framebuffer befor drawing the scene. If the color buffer is not cleared, then it stays unchanged and new rendering is drawn on top of it.

Use [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml) for this:

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    drawString(msg, 100, 100);
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

Comment: It worked for a single program, where I will create a separate context for each iteration. But when I tried it with class, For ex. I have a Text.h and Text.cpp and I am creating an object of Text class to render a text. A single Text is rendered properly, but when I try to add another object then the first object gets erased. I also tried to put them in single context but still, it is not showing properly.

Can I create multiple `context` to render multiple Text objects which will have their own context?